# Bind to count of a list inside a list

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I have the following structure:

A Shopping List is a list of strings basically, but it's made up of a list of categories with inside each a list of items.

In my `foreach` binding where I am displaying the shopping list names I also want to give the count of the number of items that are inside that list.

Basically I want something like this:

```html
<ul id="list-list" data-bind="foreach: ShoppingLists">
    <li id="list-title" class="list-title" onclick="changecolor(this)">
        <div>
            <a style="cursor: pointer" data-bind="click: $parent.ShowList">
                <span data-bind="text: Description" style="font-size: 16px; color: #252525; font-weight:bold; text-decoration: none; padding-left: 4px;"></span>
                <div style="float: right; padding-right: 4px;">
                    <a style="padding-left: 6px; color: black;" data-bind="click: $root.Edit">Edit</a>
                    <a style="padding-left: 6px; color: black;" data-bind="click: $root.Delete">Delete</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span style="padding-left: 6px; color: black;">Items in list: </span>
                    <span style="padding-left: 6px; color: black;" data-bind="text: $root.Count()"></span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

With this JavaScript:

```
Count: ko.computed(function(list){
            var val = 0;
            for(i = 0; i < $this.Categories.length; i++)
                val += $this.Categories[i].ListItems.length
            return val;
        }, this)
```

However, I can't figure out how to calculate this value properly.

Comment: You may have trimmed your code a bit *too* much. Could you extend your code and create a small repro of your scenario? We're missing some context (code wise) here to be able to easily answer your question.

Comment: okay added the html portion I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list is observable...

```
this.List = observableArray();
```

Your List object could contain your string and an observableArray of Categories:

```
this.Categories = observableArray();
```

Your Category object could contain a list of Items:

```
this.Items = observableArray();
```

You can do something like this on the Category object...

```
this.Count = ko.computed(function()
{
  return this.Items().Length;
}, this);
```

That should get you a list item count for each category.